# Entity Framework Group Results By Day

Tags: entity-framework, grouping

I have this EF Object/Table called Person with this fields

```
ID
FullName
Status
DateRegistered
```

I need to select all persons registered per day with status = 1. The result should be an object with 2 properties

- DateRegistered (A Single Day)
- List of Persons